# How to check user's phone number before send otp using Firebase in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, authentication

I'm using Firebase to send otp to user's phone number. But I don't know why my code check user's phone number after send otp instead of before send otp. How can I modify this?

This is my send otp logic:

```
let recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  recaptchaVerifier.render()
    .then(() => {
      sentOTPBtn.on('click', function () {
        const attrHref = $(this).attr('data-href');
        const attrTypeOtp = $(this).attr('data-otp-type');
        console.log(attrHref, attrTypeOtp, form.serialize())
        $.ajax({
          url: attrHref,
          type: 'POST',
          data: form.serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            if (data) {
              firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier)
                .then((confirmationResult) => {
                  confResult = confirmationResult;
                  errorMessage.hide();
                  successAuth.text("Đã gửi OTP thành công. ");
                  successAuth.show();
                  formOTP.show();
                  form.hide();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  errorMessage.text(error.message = "Gửi OTP không thành công. Vui lòng kiểm tra lại số điện thoại hoặc reCAPTCHA. ");
                  errorMessage.show();
                });
            } else {
              errorMessage.text(data.message);
              errorMessage.show();
            }
          },
          error: function (e) {
            console.log(e)
            if (attrTypeOtp === 'signup') {
              errorMessage.text("Số điện thoại không đúng định dạng hoặc đã tồn tại trên hệ thống. Vui lòng kiểm tra lại.");
              errorMessage.show();
            }
            if (attrTypeOtp === 'forgot') {
              errorMessage.text("Số điện thoại không đúng hoặc không tồn tại trên hệ thống. Vui lòng kiểm tra lại.");
              errorMessage.show();
            }
          }
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      errorMessage.text(error.message);
      errorMessage.show();
    });
```

This is my view.

```
<form action="{{ route('job-seeker.validate-signup') }}" method="POST"
                class="form-send-otp login100-form validate-form p-b-33 p-t-5">
            @csrf
            @if(session('error'))
              <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                {{ session('error') }}
              </div>
            @endif
            <div class="alert alert-danger" id="error" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
              <div class="input">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="fullName"
                  placeholder="Nhập họ và tên của bạn"
                  required
                  aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
                >
              </div>
              @error('fullName')
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ $message }}
              </div>
              @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter username">
              <div class="input d-flex align-items-center">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i>
                <div class="px-2 select-area-code">
                  <select class="form-select active phone-code" name="phone_code">
                    @foreach($country_code as $country => $code)
                      @if($code == '+84')
                        <option class="text-black" value="{{ $code }}"
                                selected>{{ $country }} {{ $code }}</option>
                      @else
                        <option class="text-black" value="{{ $code }}">{{ $country }} {{ $code }}</option>
                      @endif
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div>
                <input
                  type="tel"
                  class="input_phone"
                  placeholder="Nhập số điện thoại"
                  aria-label="phone"
                  id="phone"
                  name="phone"
                  aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
                  autofocus
                >
              </div>
              @error('phone')
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ $message }}
              </div>
              @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
              <div class="input">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Mật khẩu"
                  required
                  autocomplete="current-password"
                  aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
                >
              </div>
              @error('password')
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ $message }}
              </div>
              @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
              <div class="input">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password_confirmation"
                  placeholder="Nhập lại mật khẩu"
                  required
                  autocomplete="current-password"
                  aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
                >
              </div>
              @error('password')
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ $message }}
              </div>
              @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
              <div class="input">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-ticket"></i>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Nhập mã giới thiệu"
                  name="referrer_code"
                  aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
                  value="{{ request()->get('ma-gioi-thieu') ? request()->get('ma-gioi-thieu') : '' }}"
                >
              </div>
              @error('referrer_code')
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ $message }}
              </div>
              @enderror
            </div>
            <div id="recaptcha_container"></div>
            <p>Bằng việc đăng ký tài khoản, bạn đã đồng ý với
              <a href="#" class="active font-weight-bold text-decoration-none">Điều khoản dịch vụ</a> và
              <a href="#" class="active font-weight-bold text-decoration-none">Chính sách bảo mật</a> của chúng tôi
            </p>
            <div id="recaptcha-container" class="my-3 d-flex justify-content-center"></div>
            <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-18">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="button-submit w-100 py-2"
                id="sendOTP"
                data-otp-type="signup"
                data-href="{{ route('job-seeker.validate-signup.is-valid-phone-number') }}">
                Đăng ký
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>

          <form method="post" id="formOTP" style="display: none;">
            @csrf
            <div class="alert alert-danger" id="error" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="alert alert-success my-3" id="successOtpAuth" style="display: none"></div>
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
              <div class="input">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-key"></i>
                <input type="number" placeholder="Nhập mã OTP đã được gửi"
                       aria-label="otp" id="otp" name="otp" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping" autofocus>
              </div>
              @error('otp')
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                {{ $message }}
              </div>
              @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-18">
              <button type="button" class="button-submit w-100 py-2" id="verifyOTP">Xác nhận OTP</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

And this is my logic code.

```
class SignupController extends Controller
{

  protected $verifyAccountSE;
  private $referralCodeTask;

  public function __construct(VerifyAccountRegister $verifyAccountSE, ReferralCodeTask $referralCodeTask)
  {
    $this->verifyAccountSE = $verifyAccountSE;
    $this->referralCodeTask = $referralCodeTask;
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $country_code = BaseConstants::COUNTRY_CALLING_CODES;
    return view('job-seeker.auth.signup')->with('country_code', $country_code);
  }

  public function validateSignup(SeekerAccountSignupRequest $request)
  {
    $paras = $request->all(
      [
        'fullName',
        'password',
        'phone_code',
        'phone',
        'referrer_code'
      ]
    );
    if ($paras['referrer_code'] != null) {
      $check = $this->referralCodeTask->getByReferralCode($paras['referrer_code']);
      if (!$check) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Mã giới thiệu không hợp lệ. Vui lòng nhập lại mã giới thiệu này. ');
      }
    }
    $result = $this->verifyAccountSE->handleSignUp($paras);
    if (!$result) {
      return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Số điện thoại này đã được đăng ký trên hệ thống. Vui lòng đăng nhập bằng số điện thoại này. ');
    }
    return redirect()->route('job-seeker.login')->with('success', 'Đăng ký tài khoản thành công. ');
  }
}
```

I try using ajax. But it return "500 Internal Server Error"

```
recaptchaVerifier.render()
    .then(() => {
      sentOTPBtn.on('click', function ()  {
        const attrHref = $(this).attr('data-href');
        const attrTypeOtp = $(this).attr('data-otp-type');
        console.log(attrHref, attrTypeOtp, form.serialize())
        $.ajax({
          url: attrHref,
          type: 'POST',
          data: form.serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            if (data) {
              firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier)
                .then((confirmationResult) => {
                  confResult = confirmationResult;
                  errorMessage.hide();
                  successAuth.text("Đã gửi OTP thành công. ");
                  successAuth.show();
                  formOTP.show();
                  form.hide();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  errorMessage.text(error.message = "Gửi OTP không thành công. Vui lòng kiểm tra lại số điện thoại hoặc reCAPTCHA. ");
                  errorMessage.show();
                });
            } else {
              errorMessage.text(data.message);
              errorMessage.show();
            }
          },
          error: function (e) {
            console.log(e)
            if (attrTypeOtp === 'signup'){
              errorMessage.text("Số điện thoại không đúng định dạng hoặc đã tồn tại trên hệ thống. Vui lòng kiểm tra lại.");
              errorMessage.show();
            }
            if (attrTypeOtp === 'forgot'){
              errorMessage.text("Số điện thoại không đúng hoặc không tồn tại trên hệ thống. Vui lòng kiểm tra lại.");
              errorMessage.show();
            }
          }
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      errorMessage.text(error.message);
      errorMessage.show();
    });
```